# change image and load it to userform image word vba

Tags: vba, image, ms-word

I have shape named pic, I fill the shape with picture via VBA code, I want vba line to load the same pic into userform1 image1 once the userform load

I am using this code to fill image into the shape, just need the part ( userform1.image1.picture=ActiveDocument.Shapes("pic").UserPicture )

```
    Dim oDialog         As Word.Dialog
Dim strName As String
 
Set oDialog = Dialogs(wdDialogInsertPicture)
With oDialog
 
    .Display

     'Insert Shape Picture if the Name property (Filepath) <> ""
    If .Name <> "" Then
        With ActiveDocument.Shapes("pic").Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
            .UserPicture oDialog.Name   '   <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        End With
        UserForm1.Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(oDialog.Name)
    End If
End With
 
 ' Clean up
Set oDialog = Nothing
```

Comment: What's the problem with the code you already have? To get a picture into a user form's picture control you need to use `LoadPicture` which requires a full file path. There isn't a simple way of loading a picture from the document into a user form.

Comment: I need to load pic from document ( shape fill ), not path

Comment: Then you'll need to run the code from outside the document. The document must be saved. You'll then need to duplicate the document, change the file extension to zip, unzip the archive, extract the image you need from the /word/media folder to a temp folder, and delete the archive.  Which is what I told you last time you asked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the picture on the drive to be able to set it to the form controls. The `LoadPicture` expects a full file path.